# String errors at array Splitting Parts

Tags: java

```
 String part1=parts[0];
 String part2=parts[1];
 String part3=parts[2];
 System.out.print(part3);
```

sasdasd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asdasdasd asd asd asd
asdasdasdasd asd as asd
asdas dasd as dasd
asdasdasdasdasdasd

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you're getting an error on `System.out.println(3); `...

Comment: Check the length of the array before accessing it

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length of the array:

```
if (parts.length > 1) {
    ... // what to do if the string contains the delimiter
}
else {
    ... // what to do if the string does not contain the delimiter
}
```

Comment: Can you give me any idea Sir of how to validate a Jtextfield in the same format
as of 2d6,3d8 or 6d-10
(Numbers d Numbers) /  (Numbers d Numbers - Numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.contains("-")) {
         parts= string.split("d|\\-");    
         String part1=parts[0];
         String part2=parts[1];
         String part3=parts[2];
        }else{
             parts= string.split("d");    
             String part1=parts[0];
             String part2=parts[1];
        }

          for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(parts[i]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression with capturing groups can be used to parse the `String`. You can test the presence of the individual groups by simply checking, if the `String` for the group is `null`. Example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)d(\\d+)([+-]\\d+)?");

for (String s : new String[] {
    "2d6",
    "3d8",
    "4d6-2",
    "4d6+9",
    "2d6-10",
    "2d6-1x9"
}) {
    System.out.println(s);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        String summand = m.group(3);
        int i3 = summand == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(summand);
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}D{1}+({2})", i1, i2, i3));
    } else {
        System.out.println("no match");
    }
}
```

output:

```
2d6
2D6+(0)
3d8
3D8+(0)
4d6-2
4D6+(-2)
4d6+9
4D6+(9)
2d6-10
2D6+(-10)
2d6-1x9
no match
```